# Math cryptography module 11

Tags: math

I dont know why 3^-1 is equal to 4

```
 lambda  = (3 * 2^2 + 1)(2 * 7)^{-1}     mod 11
 = 2 * 3^-1  mod 11 
 = 2 * 4  mod 11 
 = 8
```

Why 3^-1 is equal to 4?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is only about Mathematics, and hence is best suited for Mathematics SE!

Comment: The question actually seems to be: "I dont know why 3^-1 mod 11 is equal to 4".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Inverse of  3 modulo 11 is 4, denoted by 3^(-1).

Comment: Because `3*4=12=11+1`. And dito to sasha.

Answer (score 0):

Modular exponentiation with a negative exponent follows different inverse rules:

Using Euler's theorem:
`a^(-1)` is equivalent to `a^(m-2) mod m`

so:
`3^(-1) mod 11`
`3^(11-2) mod 11`
`3^9 mod 11`
`19683 mod 11`
`4`

See [Modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Computation)